# Compute and broadcast a count in pandas (with groupby transform)

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation, split-apply-combine

How can I compute and broadcast a count in pandas?

To compute a count:

```py
df.groupby('field').size()
```

To broadcast an aggregation to the original dataframe:

```py
df.groupby('field')['field_to_aggregate'].transform(aggregation)
```

The latter works if I specify the field to aggregate onto and aggregations like `sum`, `mean`, etc. But I am not finding a way to make it work when I want a simple count of the grouped-by field.

(Note: I could just use the first and re-join on the original table against the grouped-by table, but I want to avoid joins and I'm looking for an efficient solution that uses pandas' `transform`)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
result = df.groupby('field')['field_to_aggregate'].transform('size')
```

Note that `'field_to_aggregate'` can be the same as `'field'`.